# Reverse a string using stack

Tags: java, c++, string, stack

I have been trying this for quite a while but still can't..
according to the question all we need to do id ***complete the function without making any other changes***..
we it allowed to completely re-write the code popping and dispalying the popped value might work but it doesn't.

**Question-**

```
Given a string, the task is to reverse the string using stack data structure.

Complete the function reverseString() that accepts the string, and reverses the string.
```

**Input type-**

```
The first line of input will contains an integer T denoting the no of test cases. Then T test cases follow. 
Each test case contains a number N.
Then N strings follow which are to be reversed
```

**the code on image -**

```
/* class CQStack{
      public CQStack(int s) // constructor
      public void push(int j) // put item on top of stack
      public int pop() // take item from top of stack
      public boolean isEmpty() // true if stack is empty
      public boolean isFull() // true if stack is full
    }
    CQStack class already defined as per the above blueprint
*/

static String reverseString(CQStack s, String st)
{

}
```

[image]

**Sample Input**

```
1 // No. of test cases
2 // No. of strings
CodeQuotient
Code
Sample Output
```

**output-**

```
tneitouQedoC
edoC﻿
```

Comment: Please don't post images.  And *I have been trying this for quite a while but still can't.. a*  I don't see any attempt at solving this.

Comment: It seems you're meant to use `CQStack` so basically your code just needs to do the following: 1) split the string into characters, 2) push the characters onto the stack (front to back), 3) reconstruct the string by popping them off the stack.

Comment: Note: You should only use multiple language tags if you are comparing two languages (be cautious comparing 3 or more as can quickly become too broad a question) or if you are asking about how to make 2 languages interoperate. If you don't know which language you want to implement program in, ask for the language you know best and state you are open to another language in the question. If the second-choice language is a markedly better fit for the problem, odds are good someone will let you know.

Comment: Are you mixing Java and C++?  Although it can be done, it's not recommended.  The C++ code is compiled into native assembly code.  Java is compiled into a more portable byte code (which is then run by a Java Virtual Machine).  If you are not mixing languages, please edit your tags to the language you are programming in.

Comment: If you are looking for people to give you code, you should add more languages to your tags, like LISP and Ada.

Comment: BTW, the code in the image is Java not C++.  You can drop the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks operate as last-in / first-out. So if you push all the characters from the string (in order), then pop them back off, you'll pop them off in order.

The way I prefer to iterate over the characters in a string are:

```
for (const char c: str) {
}
```

And you can build a string like this:

```
str = str + c;
```

I'm not going to actually write your code, though.